# In Drupal Site:how to display the list of corresponding users by using user reference module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters, drupal-roles

I have 3 user role that

Senior->users(senior1,senior2)

Sub_Senior->users(subsenior1,subsenior2)

junior->users(j1,j2,j3,j4)

the user subsenior1 is belonging to senior2 , user subsenior2 is belonging to senior1.

the users j1,j2 belonging to subsenior1 and users j3,j4 belonging to subsenior2 referenced by using user reference fields

but i am not able to list the corresponding users in views page like when i click the senior1 user it will list the corresponding subsenior2 user(corresponding all referenced users).

or

modules or technique is possible to create the user hierarchy and list corresponding users in views page.

I'm extremely new to drupal any one help me ..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to create a view that lists users and which takes a user id as an argument. When no user id is given it should list all users. When a user id is given the view should list all users who are referenced to the user whose id is given as the parameter.

In the views output against each user there should be a link that links to the same view with the user id of the user in the row passed as a parameter. Now clicking on that link the view will be loaded and show the child users under that user.

or

Use the **Organic Group module** for user hierarchy.